# What is happening to my model binding?

Tags: angularjs

I have a small AngularJs application that consumes a RESTful web service using `$resource`.  The resource (`salesOrderResource`) returns five objects that I bind to the model's `vm.rowData`. I write out the returned resources to the console to show that I do, indeed, have data:

[image: proof of data returned from web service]

However, once outside of the resource's `query` function, `vm.rowData` is suddenly *undefined*: 
[image: undefined message for vm.rowdata]

I can't figure out why this is happening. I am hoping someone can shed some light on what's going on here.

Here's my controller:

```js
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("SalesOrderListCtrl", ["salesOrderResource", SalesOrderListCtrl]);

    function SalesOrderListCtrl(salesOrderResource) {
        var vm = this;            

        vm.columnDefs = [
            { headerName: "Sales Order#", field: "SalesOrderNumber" },
            { headerName: "Lot#", field: "LotNumber" },
            { headerName: "Qty", field: "Quantity" },
            { headerName: "Status", field: "Status" },
            { headerName: "Branch", field: "Branch" }
        ];

        salesOrderResource.query(function (data) {
            vm.rowData = data;
            console.log("In query function:");
            console.log(vm.rowData);
        })     

        console.log("Outside query function:");
        console.log(vm.rowData);

        vm.gridOptions = {

            // PROPERTIES - object properties, myRowData and myColDefs are created somewhere in your application
            rowData: vm.rowData,
            columnDefs: vm.columnDefs,

            // PROPERTIES - simple boolean / string / number properties
            enableColResize: true,
            rowHeight: 22,
            rowSelection: "single",

            // EVENTS - add event callback handlers
            onRowClicked: function (event) { console.log("a row was clicked"); },
            onColumnResized: function (event) { console.log("a column was resized"); },
            onGridReady: function (event) { console.log("the grid is now ready"); },

            // CALLBACKS
            isScrollLag: function () { return false; }
        }           
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$resource.query is asynchronous.
Your outside query function will print before your query function finishes.

```
salesOrderResource.query(function (data) {
            vm.rowData = data;
            console.log("In query function:");
            console.log(vm.rowData);
        })
```

This will happen 1st.

```
console.log("Outside query function:");
console.log(vm.rowData);
```

Try replacing this with

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        console.log("Outside query function delayed:");
        console.log(vm.rowData);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Ah! I understand what you're saying. What led me down this path, though, is that I was trying to use `vm.rowData` in my `ag-Grid` options.  But there was nothing in `vm.rowData` when the grid options were being populated. Thanks for your help!